# sharing data between controllers in two different ng-app not working via shared service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

So I have two different html pages, two different ng-apps and two controllers. I am trying to share data between controllers and different modules.

Below is the basic structure of the application

index.html
- indexController.js
login.html
- loginController.js

sharedService.js

```
angular.module('sharedService', []).service('SharedService', function() {

var SharedService;

SharedService = (function() {

    function SharedService() {
        console.log('initializing');
    }

    var _data;
    SharedService.prototype.setData = function( data) {
        _data = data;
        /* method code... */
    };
    SharedService.prototype.getData = function( ) {
        return _data ;
    };
    return SharedService;

})();

if (typeof(window.angularSharedService) === 'undefined' || window.angularSharedService === null) {
    window.angularSharedService = new SharedService();
}
return window.angularSharedService;});


 angular.module("loginApp", ['sharedService'])
controller("loginCtrl",[
    'SharedService', function(SharedService){
    SharedService.setData(data);
    }

  angular.module("mainApp", ['sharedService'])
controller("someCtrl",[
    'SharedService', function(SharedService){
    console.log(SharedService.getData());
    }
```

The thing is since the app is different i am referenceing the

```
<script src="sharedService.js"></script>
```

the service gets initialized twice. when i set the data from loginApp sets the data but however when i query the data from mainApp, it retrieves undefined, i suspect this is because the service gets initialized again and is a different instance of sharedService

Comment: Why are you putting an instance of the service onto the `window` object? And why wrap the function in the service into a IIFE? I'd use a factory in this case and simply store the shared values inside an object in the factory and have some factory methods return or write the values.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the service will not be shared between two angular apps on different html pages.  You will need to persist the data you want to share in somewhere other than memory, such as localStorage or a remote server.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Answer (score 0):

Just played a bit with it. You can just put the `_data` you want to share between two apps onto the `window` object. Like so

```
angular.module('serv', [])
.factory('MyFactory', function () {
  window._data = 'default';
  return {
    setData: function (val) {
      console.log('setData() called with val == ', val);
      window._data = val;
    },
    getData: function () {
      return window._data;
    },
  }
});
```

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4896aiczBjMiCXazB2Kk?p=preview

Though that seems to be somewhat ugly. Probably want to at least namespace it.

Comment: seems like will just have to go with this approach